# phonegap project under SVN

Tags: cordova, svn

How to add phonegap project to version control (svn)? I have 3 projects: visionMobileApp and generated CaptureActivity, CordovaApp-CordovaLib. What is the best way to pack these projects to one which will be under version control?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I completely understand your question, but I will take a shot. Regardless of source control system (git, svn, etc),  what I do is only check in my www folder. All of the other folders, for the most part, will be build artifacts that can vary from install to install (for example, I won't have the iOS builds on a Linux machine). I would also use a build tool to create the installation, but the only thing I would check in or out is my actual source code.

If you are looking for the specific subversion commands, you should checkout http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

Comment: That is my workflow too. And I use symlinks from the original www folder to the platforms www folder.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. That is almost what I would like to know. I was not sure what is necessary to preserve (save in svn) if I want restore the project. **I tried to "restore" my phonegap project and _www_ folder with _config.xml_ was enough** to do so. But what about _mainfests_ (which is generated) and it stores a target (android) version etc.? And what about plugins? How to control version of plugins used in phonegap project?

Comment: Well... I found that it's possible to do both (**manage plugins version and modify platform specific configuration files** -e.g. AndroidManifest.xml) **with config.xml**: http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.3.0/configuring_basics.md.html http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.3.0/configuring_plugins.md.html#Plugins

Comment: Cool. I will definitely check out that link as well, although I use configuration management tools to spin up my development environments.